# How to lowercase a variable expansion

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I have the following code and variables declared. How do I make sure that **$shared_mailbox_alias** becomes lowercase when expanded to the Mailbox creation cmdlet below? Since it's based on **$Project_code** which is typed in capital letters:

```
$Project_number = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the Project Number ie. 02XXX'
$Project_code = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the Project Code (in capital letters) ie. CRE'
$Project_name = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is the Project extended Name ie. Victoria Station Platform'

$shared_mailbox_displayname = "File: $Project_name"
$shared_mailbox_name = "$Project_code"
$shared_mailbox_alias = "file.$Project_code"

New-Mailbox -Shared -DisplayName $shared_mailbox_displayname -Name $shared_mailbox_name -Alias $shared_mailbox_alias -PrimarySmtpAddress $shared_mailbox_primarysmtp
```

My goal is to have an alias of "file.abc" rather than "file.ABC", and I cannot change the way it is been given as input (ABC) since I have other cmdlets that create folders with that syntax.

Cheers

Comment: Use the `ToLower()` method.

Comment: thanks! do you mean declaring the variable once more, like so: $shared_mailbox_alias = $shared_mailbox_alias.ToLower()

Comment: @pakyrs, it's unneccessary to declare another variable.  `$shared_mailbox_name = $Project_code.ToLower()`  or  `$shared_mailbox_name = "$($Project_code.ToLower())"` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, thanks for the input, this is the syntax I used:

```
$shared_mailbox_alias = "file.$($Project_code.ToLower())"
```